# Google Cloud: How to programmatically schedule recurring tasks?

Tags: asp.net, cron, .net-core, google-cloud-platform, scheduled-tasks

I want to build a task scheduling service on the Google Cloud Platform. The tasks can be as simple as triggering a URL. Tasks can be recurring (once an hour, twice a day, every thursday, ...) and can be created and removed dynamically.

Which services/APIs on the Google Cloud Platform can I use for this?

I have looked into Google App Engine cron jobs but there seems to be no way to programmatically modify them. If possible I would like to avoid running a cron job every minute just to check if there is some task to run.

My framework of choice is ASP.NET Core but if there is a better solution available, e.g. in Java, I'm willing to try it out.

Comment: See my answer here, which recommends using Google Cloud Scheduler https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12116799/adding-dynamic-cron-jobs-to-gae/56230135#56230135

Answer (score 2):

As you have found out, App Engine Cron Service does not have an API for programmatically managing cron tasks. Cron tasks are configured using a file called `cron.yaml` and this file can be programmatically modified and uploaded to google cron service([details](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/go/scheduling-jobs-with-cron-yaml)). I'm not sure about exact requirements for your task scheduling service, bu this could be a good enough solution for your problem.

Another option would be to run a Google compute engine instance. As this is basically a virtual server maintained by you, you will have full control over it; allowing you to choose OS, backend/frontend technologies etc. For example you can run a Linux server, use an asp.net core backend to manage crontab tasks.

Comment: What do you mean about `cron.yaml` file can be programmatically modified? I think it's static

Comment: @slideshowp2 what I mean is that the file can be updated and re-submitted by the task-scheduling service the question owner wants to implement

Comment: re-submitted? You mean redeploy the cron tasks after updating `cron.yaml` file?

Answer (score 2):

I would also recommend to take a look on Google Cloud Tasks. You can create queues and push/pull tasks to/from them:

> - **Push queues** run tasks by delivering HTTP requests to App Engine worker services. They dispatch these requests at a reliable, steady
>     rate and guarantee reliable task execution. Because you can control
>     the rate at which tasks are sent from the queue, you can control the
>     workers' scaling behavior and hence your costs.
> - **Pull queues** do not dispatch tasks at all. They depend on other worker services to "lease" tasks from the queue on their own
>     initiative. Pull queues give you more power and flexibility over when
>     and where tasks are processed, but they also require you to do more
>     process management. When a task is leased the leasing worker declares
>     a deadline. By the time the deadline arrives the worker must either
>     complete the task and delete it or the Task Queue service will allow
>     another worker to lease it.

Source: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/taskqueue/