# 2019: Dynamic cron jobs Google App Engine

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, cron, google-cloud-platform

I am developing a reporting service (i.e. Database reports via email) for a project on Google App Engine, naturally using the Google Cloud Platform.

I am using Python and Django but I feel that may be unimportant to my question specifically. I want to be able to allow users of my application schedule specific cron reports to send off at specified times of the day.

**I know** this is completely possible by running a cron on **GAE** on a minute-by-minute basis (using `cron.yaml` since I'm using Python) and providing the logic to determine which reports to run in whatever view I decide to make the cron hit, but this seems terribly inefficient to me, and seeing as the best answer I have found suggests doing the same thing ([Adding dynamic cron jobs to GAE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12116799/8382028)), I wanted an "updated" suggestion.

Is there at this point in time a better option than running a cron every minute and checking a DB full of client entries to determine which report to fire off?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to have a look at the new [Google Cloud Scheduler](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/) service (in beta at the moment), which is a fully managed cron job service. It allows you to create cron jobs programmatically via its REST API. So you could create a specific cron job per customer with the appropriate schedule to fit you needs.

Comment: this seems awesome, but unfortunately I am not 'seeing' a way for this to be accomplished within my application on a dynamic basis. `To create a job you can use either the console or the gcloud command line.` from https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/creating is great, but GAE does not allow terminal commands to be executed (as far as I have read) from a published application so gcloud is out and so is the console because I have to login to use the UI. Can you provide an example of how you'd accomplish this programmatically given those restraints?

Comment: @ViaTech The REST api uses plain HTTP requests: https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects.locations.jobs/create

Comment: @Dan Cornilescu, okay that makes much more sense, thank you! I'm inclined to mark this as the correct answer, let me give it another day to see if any other ideas surface before I mark this correct.

Answer (score 2):

Given this limit, my guess would be NO

> Free applications can have up to 20 scheduled tasks. Paid applications can have up to 250 scheduled tasks.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/cronref#limits

Another version of your minute-by-minute workaround would be a daily cron task that finds everyone that wants to be launched that day, and then use the `_eta` argument to pinpoint the precise moment in each day for each task to launch.

Comment: hmm your alternate solution does seem interesting, but there would be limitations on same-day scheduling of tasks if a user schedules a task after the daily cron runs. For example, a user wants a report to fire off at 8pm and schedules it at 4pm that same day.